# Jest Spyon is not mocking a method of a class

Tags: typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have two separate classes where one class is calling a function from another class. Now I am trying to Test with jest wether the function is called.

**Pokemon Class (/pokemon/pokemon.service.ts)**

```
import ApiInterface from "../utils/api";

export default class PokemonService {
  private readonly apiInteface: ApiInterface;
  constructor() {
    this.apiInteface = new ApiInterface();
  }

  public getByName = <T>(name: string): Promise<T> => {
    return this.apiInteface.get(`pokemon/${name}`);
  };
}
```

**Evolution Class (/evolution/evolution.service.ts)**

```
import PokemonService from "../pokemon/pokemon.service";
import { IPokemon } from "../types/types";

export default class EvolutionService {
  private pokemonService: PokemonService;
  constructor() {
    this.pokemonService = new PokemonService();
  }

  public chainByName = async (name: string) => {
    const pokemon: IPokemon = await this.pokemonService.getByName(name);
    return pokemon;
  };
}
```

**Test file (/evolution/evolution.service.spec.ts)**

```
import EvolutionService from "./evolution.service";
import PokemonService from "../pokemon/pokemon.service";

const pokemonService = new PokemonService();
const evolutionService = new EvolutionService();

beforeAll(() => {
  jest
    .spyOn(pokemonService, "getByName")
    .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ a: "as" }));
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

test("good response", async () => {
  await evolutionService.chainByName("eevee");
  expect(pokemonService.getByName).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

[image: Now the error I am getting is this error.]

Can someone please guide me though?

I have tried using `jest.mock('../pokemon/pokemon.service').mockImplementation` and `jest.mock('../pokemon/pokemon.service').mockResolvedValue` as well.

Comment: What do you think is the connection between the `pokemonService` you defined in the test and the `evolutionService` you're testing? Read up on inverting the dependency, it would make your code much easier to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I completely miss that part. The service I was mocking is not the one running in the `evolutionService`. It is needed to be injected.

Answer (score 0):

`jest.mock()` can't create a mock function for `getByName()` function of `pokemon.service` module. From the [Automatic mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock)
 documentation, we know:

> If you use arrow functions in your classes, they will not be part of the mock. The reason for that is that arrow functions are not present on the object's prototype, they are merely properties holding a reference to a function.

We can still use `jest.mock()` to mock `PokemonService` from `pokemon.service` module and get the class instance(created in the `constructor` of the `EvolutionService`  class) via [`mockFn.mock.instances`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockinstances). When we get the
instance, we can use a mock function to replace the `getByName()` function.

*Note: The module path in the demo is different.*

E.g.

`pokemon.service.ts`:

```
export default class PokemonService {
    constructor() {}

    public getByName = <T>(name: string): Promise<T> => {
        return Promise.resolve('real name' as T);
    };
}
```

`evolution.service.ts`:

```
import PokemonService from './pokemon.service';

export default class EvolutionService {
    private pokemonService: PokemonService;
    constructor() {
        this.pokemonService = new PokemonService();
    }

    public chainByName = async (name: string) => {
        const pokemon = await this.pokemonService.getByName(name);
        return pokemon;
    };
}
```

`evolution.service.spec.ts`:

```
import EvolutionService from './evolution.service';
import PokemonService from './pokemon.service';

jest.mock('./pokemon.service');

const PokemonServiceMock = PokemonService as jest.MockedClass<typeof PokemonService>;

test('good response', async () => {
    const evolutionService = new EvolutionService();
    const pokemonServiceInstance = PokemonServiceMock.mock.instances[0];
    pokemonServiceInstance.getByName = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('fake name');
    const actual = await evolutionService.chainByName('eevee');
    expect(pokemonServiceInstance.getByName).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(actual).toBe('fake name');
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76501591/evolution.service.spec.ts (7.28 s)
  ✓ good response (2 ms)

----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                  | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files             |      80 |      100 |      60 |   77.78 |                   
 evolution.service.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 pokemon.service.ts   |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |   33.33 | 4-5               
----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.571 s, estimated 8 s
```